# Getting Json element value from the Element ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, selenium, nightwatch.js

Have another question while learning javascript and the javascript fm. So I would like to understand how is it possible to access to

```
{ Element: 1 }, { Element: 2},...
```

Because inside this is the detailed information about this array.

And the next step, I need to make it like a json format where executes like

```
[{name: "MyName", surname: "mySurname"}, {name: "MyName", surname: "mySurname"}]
```

and like that but I need to get this for any of the

```
{ Element:1}, {Element:2}, ....
```

I'm using the nightwatch.js and my code right now looks like :

```
.elements('css selector', 'ul li', function(res){
    console.log(res.value)
    console.log(res.value[1].ELEMENT)
    browser.elementIdAttribute(res.value[1].ELEMENT, 'li', function(newRes) {
      console.log(newRes.value)
    })
  })
```

this executes

---

```
[ { ELEMENT: '1' },
  { ELEMENT: '2' },
  { ELEMENT: '3' },
  { ELEMENT: '4' } ]
2
null
```

---

Here is html:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<ul class="random">
    <li class="list">
        <div class="name">Nick</div>
        <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
        <div class="age">22</div>
        <div class="city">London</div>
    </li>

    <li class="list odd">
        <div class="name">Nick</div>
        <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
        <div class="age">22</div>
        <div class="city">London</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <div class="name">Nick</div>
        <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
        <div class="age">22</div>
        <div class="city">London</div>
    </li>

    <li class="list odd">
        <div class="name">Nick</div>
        <div class="surname">Kyrgios</div>
        <div class="age">22</div>
        <div class="city">London</div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is link to the documentation (if needed) http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elementIdValue

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is not possible.

You get `null` because you're using the wrong command.
As you can see here, it is used to *set* values to elements.
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/lib/api/element-commands.js#L293

What you actually want is to use `.elementIdText` like:

```
module.exports = {
  'Test' : function(browser) {

    function iterate(elements) {
      elements.value.forEach(function(el) {
        browser.elementIdText(el.ELEMENT, function(r) {
          console.log(r.value);
        });
      });
    }

    browser
      .url('http://simsonivini.lv/nightwatch.php')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 8000)
      .elements('css selector', 'ul li div', iterate)
      .end();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting result like this : Nick Kyrgios 22 London 4 times, how to make it into the json format?